# In this node definition, why are we using the "Node" after the structure definition?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

```
typedef struct node
{
 int data;
 struct node *next;
}Node;  // ???
```

I don't understand why we use the Node after the definition. What function does is perform? Does it prevent the structure from pointing to itself infinitely? 
Question might sound stupid, by i'm still learning. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `Node` after the structure definition, because there's a `typedef` before it.

The structure definition by itself would be this:

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
```

Since this is C++, that would be enough to refer to the structure type by the name `node`. However it seems the person who wrote it is originally either from a C background, or aiming to provide a C compatible header. In C, you'd have to refer it as `struct node`, which some find verbose. So the person in question immediately provided a type alias. The code you presented is equivalent to:

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node Node;
```

And it allows us to refer to the same type by the name `Node`, in either C or C++.

Comment: Yes, my instructor has a C background. And I'm not so familiar with it.
I had no idea that "struct" keyword is optional in C++ but mandatory in C while creating a struct object. This was the root cause of all the confusion. Thank you.

Comment: @hawkeyes21 - Well, C is a sister language to C++. It'd be better if your instructor wasn't teaching C-ish stuff, but you need to work with what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

Here, You have Defined a struct, and declare a structure variable at the same time. `typedef` keyword is used in creating a type `Node`, which is of type as `struct node`.

So, you can easily use `Node n1;` instead of `struct node n1`.

Comment: Okay, so in other words, while creating a new node, I can either use node *p (small n) or Node *p (capital N). Both of them would mean the same?